# Pyglets image.save('file.png') doesn't save modifications to img-data

Tags: python, image-processing, python-3.x, pyglet

I got a strange phenomenon when working with pyglets `.save()` function.
When i leave it out of the code the output of the application looks like this:
[image]

The black area is the main window object, the gray area is the `graph()` class and the green line is modified data of the graph's pixel-data, so the green line is not an overlay or a separate object, it's part of the pixeldata itself.

As soon as i add `self.texture.save()` (the gray+green pixel data), the screen goes black (it's just as if `self.texture` goes full alpha on me or the pixeldata simply disappears) and the `kitten.png` ([example code for saving images](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/programming_guide/saving_an_image.html)) file looks like:
[image]

(yea it's blank/transparent in case you thought i was trolling...)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pyglet, sys, select

...

class Graph(pyglet.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color="#C2C2C2", x=None, y=None, plotpoints=[], maxx=None, maxy=None):
        self.texture = self.gen_solid_img(width+20, height+20, color)

        tmp = self.texture.get_image_data()
        data = tmp.get_data('RGBA', tmp.width * 4)
        ## YXColorMap converts the string-data representing the image
        ## into a dictionary of map[y][x] = pixeldata
        data = YXColorMap(data, tmp.width)

        ## Now here's where i can do:
        ## data[y][x] = (255,255,255,255)
        ## to say, modify x,y pixel to completely white.

        ## And i do this via plot-points
        ## (yes, ugly and not mathematically fast, but it works.
        for item in plotpoints:
            data[item[1]][item[0]] = IntToColor(*item[2])

        ## MapToString stitches dictionary-obj back
        ## to a string object that can be used in pyglet.
        data = MapToString(data)

        ## Then we set that data as the texture,
        ## In theory this should replace the entire texture?
        self.texture.set_data('RGBA', tmp.width * 4, data)

        ## Rendering the image up until this point works fine..
        ## As soon as i do this however the image goes blank:
        ## (example copied straight from the pyglet website)
        self.texture.save('kitten.png') #even with file=.. it's broken

        ## This would fix the rendering issue, but not the file on disk:
        # Not sure why i would need to re-set the "data" after .save()
        # but it will render the green line again instead of nothing.
        # self.texture.set_data('RGBA', tmp.width * 4, data)

        super(Graph, self).__init__(self.texture, x=x, y=y)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def gen_solid_img(self, width, height, c):
        if type(c) == str:
            c = c.lstrip("#")
            c = max(6-len(c),0)*"0" + c
            r = int(c[:2], 16)
            g = int(c[2:4], 16)
            b = int(c[4:], 16)
            a = 0.2*255
        elif type(c) == tuple:
            r, g, b, a = c
        c = (r,g,b,a)
        return pyglet.image.SolidColorImagePattern(c).create_image(width, height)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but it I found it from a Google search, so I hope that this answer can help anyone else looking for a similar thing.

I've had a hack at the code, and here is what I have come up with:

```
import pyglet

def YXColorMap(data, width, format_length):
    YX = [data[i:i+format_length] for i in range(0, len(data), format_length)]
    return [YX[i:i+width] for i in range(0, len(YX), width)]

def MapToString(colour_map):
    YX = [item for row in colour_map for item in row]
    return bytes([b for item in YX for b in item])

class Graph(pyglet.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color="#C2C2C2", width=640, height=480, x=0, y=0, plotpoints=[], maxx=None, maYX=None):
        texture = self.gen_solid_img(width, height, color)

        tmp = texture.get_image_data()
        data = tmp.get_data('RGBA', tmp.width * 4)
        colour_map = YXColorMap(data, tmp.width, 4)

        for yP, xP, color in plotpoints:
            colour_map[yP][xP] = color

        tmp.set_data('RGBA', tmp.width * 4, MapToString(colour_map))

        super().__init__(texture)

        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def save_image(self, fileName):
        self._texture.save(fileName)

    def gen_solid_img(self, width, height, c):
        if type(c) == str:
            c = c.lstrip("#")
            c = max(6-len(c),0)*"0" + c
            r = int(c[:2], 16)
            g = int(c[2:4], 16)
            b = int(c[4:], 16)
            a = int(0.2 * 255)
        elif type(c) == tuple:
            r, g, b, a = c

        c = (r,g,b,a)
        return pyglet.image.SolidColorImagePattern(c).create_image(width, height)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    plotpoints = [(x+2, x, (0, 0, 255, 255)) for x in range(0, 360)]

    window = pyglet.window.Window()
    graph = Graph(plotpoints=plotpoints)

    def on_draw():
        graph.draw()

    window.on_draw = on_draw

    graph.save_image('kitten.png')
    pyglet.app.run()
```

It should open up a window with a diagonal blue line and save the graph to a file called `kitten.png`

I think the problem with the code in the question is perhaps a confusion between `self.texture` and `self._texture`, where `self.texture` is a variable assigned by the Graph class, and `self._texture` is the texture of the sprite.